# How to use Client ID and Client Secret to fetch API in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, authentication, oauth, secret-key, clientid

I am trying to make an api call in Javascript. I am fetching a URL and passing in options, as shown in the image. I am unable to access the API, because I believe I am not passing in my client ID and client secret properly. I also have a redirect URI, but I am unsure of how to specify these in my options and what the syntax is.

Does anyone have any advice on how I can specify this information? Also, is using btoa to convert it to base64 incorrect?

My options I am passing in to my fetch request:

```
  const options = {
    method: 'GET',
    json: true,
    agent: agent,
    headers: {
      Authorization: 'Basic ' + btoa(client_id + ':' + client_secret),
      redirect_uri: `{URI HERE}

       }

      }
```

[My options I am passing in to my fetch request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qh2Mq.png)
Thank you

Comment: Post the code, not an image of the code. We can not copy and paste text from an image.

Comment: Right, edited. Any idea how I can be passing in my variables differently?

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: I'm using this request to be used in GraphQL. When I query the data that should be returned from the API, I just received "null" in those fields which is not the case